# Make list of 2-value tuples of all possible combinations of another list

Tags: python, list, scipy

Having such list

```
['Jack Matthews', 'Mick LaSalle', 'Claudia Puig', 'Lisa Rose', 'Toby', 'Gene Seymour']
```

How can I make a list where all possible combinations of item from above list will be stored, like this

```
 [('Jack Matthews', 'Toby'), ('Jack Matthews', 'Claudia Puig'), ('Jack Matthews', 'Lisa Rose')] # and so on
```

I need above tuples for this function

```
 def euclidean_distance(preferences_dict, person_1, person_2):
    shared_items = {}
    for item in preferences_dict[person_1]:
            if item in preferences_dict[person_2]:
                    shared_items[item] = 1

    if not len(shared_items):
            return
    sum_of_squares = sqrt(sum([pow(preferences_dict[person_1][item] - preferences_dict[person_2][item], 2) for item in preferences_dict[person_1] if item in preferences_dict[person_2]]))
    return 1/(1+sum_of_squares)
```

and this data set

```
critics={'Lisa Rose': {'Lady in the Water': 2.5, 'Snakes on a Plane': 3.5,
'Just My Luck': 3.0, 'Superman Returns': 3.5, 'You, Me and Dupree': 2.5,
'The Night Listener': 3.0},
 'Gene Seymour': {'Lady in the Water': 3.0, 'Snakes on a Plane': 3.5,
'Just My Luck': 1.5, 'Superman Returns': 5.0, 'The Night Listener': 3.0,
'You, Me and Dupree': 3.5},
'Michael Phillips': {'Lady in the Water': 2.5, 'Snakes on a Plane': 3.0,
'Superman Returns': 3.5, 'The Night Listener': 4.0},
'Claudia Puig': {'Snakes on a Plane': 3.5, 'Just My Luck': 3.0,
'The Night Listener': 4.5, 'Superman Returns': 4.0,
'You, Me and Dupree': 2.5},
'Mick LaSalle': {'Lady in the Water': 3.0, 'Snakes on a Plane': 4.0,
'Just My Luck': 2.0, 'Superman Returns': 3.0, 'The Night Listener': 3.0,
'You, Me and Dupree': 2.0},
'Jack Matthews': {'Lady in the Water': 3.0, 'Snakes on a Plane': 4.5,
'The Night Listener': 4.5, 'Superman Returns': 4.0, 'You, Me and Dupree':    1.0},
'Toby': {'Snakes on a Plane':4.5,'You, Me and Dupree':1.0,'Superman Returns':4.0}}
```

I want to count Euclidean distance between 2 critics on each movie.
What will be the best way to count this value for each pair of critics, excluding repeated
I thought about this

```
names = dict([(critic, critics.keys()) for critic in critics.keys()])
for critic in names.keys():
    if critic in names[critic]:
            names[critic].remove(critic)
actual_distance = []
for base_critic in names.keys():
    for critic in names[base_critic]:
            actual_distance.append(euclidean_distance(critics, base_critic, critic))
```

Problem with this code is that it have duplicate values, because names['Jack Matthews'] has value 'Toby' and vice versa

Comment: Please! If you've done research, **show it**. From [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): *"Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update*: Now the situation looks a bit different as you updated the question. Here's a quick snippet thrown together using `pandas` and `numpy` (for the sake of simplicity we replace missing ratings with zero):

```
import numpy as np
importport pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

df = pd.DataFrame(critics).T.fillna(0)
```

[image: Sample data]

```
distances = []
for critic1, critic2 in combinations(df.index, 2):
    ratings1 = df.ix[critic1].values
    ratings2 = df.ix[critic2].values
    dist = np.sqrt(np.sum(ratings1 - ratings2) ** 2) # euclidian distance
    distances.append((dist, critic1, critic2))

pd.DataFrame(distances, columns=['distance', 'critic1', 'critic2']).sort('distance', ascending=False).head(5)
```

[image: critics]

So there you have it. Gene Seymour and Toby strongly disagree with their ratings.

Comment: This will return the same pairing twice, which might be what the OP wants, but isn't what I'd guess from the word "combinations".

Comment: Given the down-votes, we'll book that under "lacking specs" ;) But of course, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> names = ['Jack Matthews', 'Mick LaSalle', 'Claudia Puig', 'Lisa Rose', 'Toby', 'Gene Seymour']
>>> combos = itertools.combinations(names, 2)
>>> for name1, name2 in combos:
...     print(name1, name2)
... 
('Jack Matthews', 'Mick LaSalle')
('Jack Matthews', 'Claudia Puig')
('Jack Matthews', 'Lisa Rose')
('Jack Matthews', 'Toby')
('Jack Matthews', 'Gene Seymour')
('Mick LaSalle', 'Claudia Puig')
('Mick LaSalle', 'Lisa Rose')
('Mick LaSalle', 'Toby')
('Mick LaSalle', 'Gene Seymour')
('Claudia Puig', 'Lisa Rose')
('Claudia Puig', 'Toby')
('Claudia Puig', 'Gene Seymour')
('Lisa Rose', 'Toby')
('Lisa Rose', 'Gene Seymour')
('Toby', 'Gene Seymour')
```

Comment: Or use `itertools.product` if you also want self-pairings.